# Laravel Polymorphic Relationships - Return child with parent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a model Team with has a polymorphic relationship with Marketcenters Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Team extends Model
{
    public function teamable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
    
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Marketcenter extends Model
{
    public function teams()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Team', 'teamable');
    }
}
```

I need to retrieve all teams for one or any Marketcenter so I can list all Teams and to which Marketcenter they belong.

So I execute the following code and I get a collection od Teams for the Market Center in query:

```
$marketcenters = Marketcenter::where('id', $request->user()->marketcenter->id)->with('teams')->get();
    foreach($marketcenters as $marketcenter) {
        dd($marketcenter->teams);
    }
```

But my problem appears when I want to retrieve each Team with their corresponding Market Center:

```
$marketcenters = Marketcenter::where('id', $request->user()->marketcenter->id)->with('teams')->get();
    foreach($marketcenters as $marketcenter) {
        dd($marketcenter->teams->marketcenter->mc_name);
    }
```

> Property [marketcenter] does not exist on this collection instance.

How can I retrieve parent data to child record in a Polymoprphic relationship?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try querying for teams instead of the market center:

```
$teams = Team::whereHas('teamable', function ($q) {
    $q->whereKey(request()->user()->marketcenter->id);
})->get();
```

Also, from the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations):

> You may also retrieve the owner of a polymorphic relation from the polymorphic model by accessing the name of the method that performs the call to morphTo.

```
// This gets the marketcenter
$team->teamable
```

Comment: thanks for your help. That suggestion worked with this code refactoring:


**Controller**

`$marketcenters = Marketcenter::where('id', $request->user()->marketcenter->id)->with('teams')->get();`

Answer (score 1):

my question is why you want to access "marketcenter" via team model like $marketcenter->teams->marketcenter->mc_name instead you can directly use $marketcenter->mc_name in the for loop as both would return you the same object.

If you still need it than you have to have another foreach loop for martketcenter->team as you have morphMany so it would return you collection object from team model if you want marketplace than you have to call teamable function that would return the object of morphed model which may be Marketcenter or may not be depending on the morphed model attached to that record

Comment: Thanks @Hamza
I need to have teams record with team name and market center name to which they belong in have row, tjat's why I'm trying to access $marketcenter->teams->marketcenter->mc_name in loop

Comment: But you can't as  $marketcenter->teams is a collection as it has morphMany,  and other thing is there is no relationship like  marketcenter defined on Team model, please post entire Team and marketplace model if possible

Comment: The two model are Team and Marketcenter with a polymorphic relationship, both are in first post, there is no additonal model in this relationship between them. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I know but your team model does not have marketcenter relationship it has teamable as morph so you would have to use teamable instead of marketcenter before that you have to $marketcenter->teams as it is morphMany

Comment: Thanks @Hamza ! I found the solution, I will post under other answer.